# cube.js playground not plotting data correctly

Tags: cube.js

I am using cube.js to compare the change in data over the time by plotting it as a line graph .

Step 1 :
After generating cube.js schema successfully , data looks like this:

[image]

Step 2 :

Now, while I am trying to check the line graph, it's showing the line as below . No line is formatted. Unfortunately, it's not working for the bar graph also .

[image]

Moreover, in SQL the data type for the value is :  float(10,10) and timestamp

Apart from that, cube.js console has not error trace , rather its working fine :

```
Performing query: scheduler-0070c129-f83a-45db-ae09-aac6f9858200
Executing SQL: scheduler-0070c129-f83a-45db-ae09-aac6f9858200
--
  SELECT FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 10) as refresh_key
```

Moreover , I tried as below :  [all time ,w/o grouping and  pivot settings as I need ] , yet no luck ,
[image]

However, If I add measure count , the count is plotting the lie not the expected y-axis data as I configured in pivot settings.

[image]

**My question is : what's going wrong ?**

Comment: is this a chartjs question?

Comment: It's cubejs (https://cube.dev/)  and chartjs is the engine using by cubejs , I can not create the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goal was to generate a line graph for the change of a numerical value over time:

x-axis: date/time.
y-axis: my numerical value.

Cube.js Generated the following schema for my data.
The problem with this schema was that **String Type** was assigned to the age dimension(clearly should be a Number). Moreover ,there are no **measures** for filed **age** ,which I am trying to plot.

```
cube(`ConceptDrifts`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM cube.concept_drifts`,
  preAggregations: {
  },
  joins: {
    
  },
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [date]
    },
    testCount: {
      sql: `test_count`,
      type: `sum`
    }
  },
  dimensions: {
    age: {
      sql: `age`,
      type: `string`
    },
    maxAge: {
      sql: `max_age`,
      type: `string`
    },
    sex: {
      sql: `sex`,
      type: `string`
    },
    sexSd: {
      sql: `sex_sd`,
      type: `string`
    },
    date: {
      sql: `date`,
      type: `time`
    }
  },
  dataSource: `default`
});
```

Therefore, I changed the schema at **/cube/conf/schema#** manually

Added new measures a:

```
   ag :{
     type : `number`,
     sql : `age`,       
     drillMembers : [age]           
    }
```

And, changed the type (as **number** ) in dimensions  :

```
 dimensions: {
    age: {
      sql: `age`,
      type: `number`
    },
    
    maxAge: {
      sql: `max_age`,
      type: `number`
    },
    
    sex: {
      sql: `sex`,
      type: `number`
    },
    
    sexSd: {
      sql: `sex_sd`,
      type: `number`
    },
    
    date: {
      sql: `date`,
      type: `time`
    }
  },
  
  dataSource: `default`
});
```

As a result, the graph looks like below :

[image]

More reference :

[Data Schema Concepts](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/fundamentals/concepts)
[Drilldowns](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/fundamentals/additional-concepts)

Comment: That's great, I get now that you generated the schema automatically, A general rule of thumb for analytics is to always start with gathering the questions you want your data to answer, then proceed to define schema with measures and dimensions that will help answer those questions.

Comment: Yes indeed , questions > schema > answers .